How to auto-shutdown postgresql with timeout?
I have here a simple PostgreSQL instance, generated by a build script. The goal is to make it automatically safe shutdown, if it has no new connection request for a while (like 5 min or so).
What is the best way to do it? postgresql.conf and similars are surprisingly silent in such question.

Important thing is that this db instance has an uncommon lifecycle, because it is essentially part of a build automatization script. This script can start it as needed, then some things run to create a db in it, this db is dumped, and the instance can be stopped. Goal is to make this workflow better by making the db auto-stopping.

There is no automatic way to do that.
Perhaps the following is good enough:

configure log_connection = on and log_disconnection = on, so that all connections and disconnections write a line in the log file

have a cron job on the database server that checks the following two things every 5 minutes:

the modification timestamp of the PostgreSQL log file

the number of PostgreSQL processes



if the log file didn't get modified in the last 5 minutes, and the number of PostgreSQL processes is only the count of postmaster + background processes (6 on v16 with default settings), shut down PostgreSQL


